# Presto reorder columns without knowing all the column names

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I would like to query a table, but reorganize the columns a little bit.

I would like to move `2` columns as the first and second columns, kind of like

```
SELECT colB, colC, * FROM some_table
```

But the problem with this is that `colB` and `colC` will duplicated, since the `*` will extract it again as well.

Is there a way to do this without knowing all the column names and always having column 1 and 2 as `colB` and `colC`?  And then the rest of the columns will be in whatever order

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in Presto. Have you tried creating a view with required columns and query?

Comment: I have not tried that